# Apache POI SXSSFWorkbook: date style is not applied/not working

Tags: apache-poi

We are using the Apache POI library to create Excel sheets from our application.

For memory reasons (our application creates huge sheets (>150'000 lines) and this caused memory consumption spikes of >3GB) I had to switch from the default (XSSF)Workbook to the sliding window variant (**S**XSSFWorkbook).

Most features worked as expected (except for the autosizing of columns for which one now has to call `trackAllColumnsForAutoSizing()` after creation of the sheet) but for one most annoying bug:
The assignment of date-styles does not seem to work anymore!

The code that creates the style we use for date-cells is:

```
protected CellStyle createDateCellStyle() {
    SXSSFCreationHelper createHelper = (SXSSFCreationHelper)workbook.getCreationHelper();
    CellStyle cellStyle = workbook.createCellStyle();
    cellStyle.setDataFormat(createHelper.createDataFormat().getFormat("dd.MM.yyyy"));
    return cellStyle;
}
```

(I changed the original `CreationHelper` to `SXSSFCreationHelper` during my experiments to get this working, but it didn't change anything.

After creation of a data cell we simply assign the date-style to the relevant cells:

```
cell.setCellStyle(dateStyle);
```

But instead of being displayed as dates all cells that are supposed to be formatted as dates are instead formatted as integers. :-(

[image: Excel displaying date cells as integers...]

The very same code works without glitch using the "all-in-memory" variant of POI sheets.

Is that a known bug? Do there exist fixes or workarounds for this?

We are using Java 8, POI version 5.2.3 (the latest at the time of this writing).
Our runtime is Tomcat v7 (but I doubt this is relevant here).

Comment: are you creating date style once or are you creating it multiple times? Excel has a limit on the number of styles and if you create the styles over and over, they can be misapplied.

Comment: @PJ Fanning: Once only. The method is part of the initialization code (`dateStyle = createDateCellStyle()`) and the lower snippet is part of the later content creation loop.

Comment: I just added https://github.com/apache/poi/commit/1639f8b923bb4a56e56bf76d1b8dd3449a7f1814 and this seems to work ok.

Comment: Aaarg! The classical IT situation. It works for you but not for me. :-(  What could possibly influence that or make the difference here? Language settings (I run my system using en_US)? Anything else? What comes to my mind: your UT essentially checks POI against itself. Could you write that sheet to a file and try to open that in Excel afterwards? We are using Microsoft® Excel® for Microsoft 365 MSO (Version 2212 Build 16.0.15928.20278) 32-bit.

Comment: I loaded a file built from my test into the excel webapp and it had the right date format display.

Comment: Thanks - I appreciate your effort! I am running out of wits what could cause this difference. I am now even emitting the result of "getDataFormatString()" on these cells but it looks perfectly valid to me: `"dd.MM.yyyy"` (that's the german style of writing dates). Beats me why Excel decides to display these as integers. I added a screenshot of these cells.

Comment: @PJFanning: Thanks and Kudos to for testing this! Your comment and tests convinced me that it was NOT a bug in the library but there must lurk some issue in **our** code!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As turned out the resaon for the cells not properly shown as dates was an invalid sequence of createCell() and getCell(). Our code accidentally called getCell() with `MissingCellPolicy.CREATE_NULL_AS_BLANK` and assigned it the desired style BEFORE calling the createCell()-method on the same row and column (thus overwriting the previously obtained cell with a cell without style). That was the reason why the cell was then formatted as number/integer.

What beats me is: this code (in that very sequence!) has "worked" for years and I hadn't changed anything in it. Apparently the setValue(Date) method must have assigned a Date-format by default in earlier versions. Or else I have no explanation why Date-cells always showed up properly formatted as date until I had migrated to the latest POI version and the streaming variant of Workbooks where the values suddenly showed up as numbers.